# Why do I get a ByRef argument type mismatch error even though my input is the correct variable type?

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

I am working on a code that, in certain situations, creates a new sheet that contains two buttons. One button makes a UserForm appear and asks the user a few questions to format the newly created sheet. The user then inputs data into the tables that have now appeared and finally clicks the second button called "Execute."

The "Execute" button simply takes all of the input data and does some calculations using a Sub called `MathCode(ws As Worksheet)` but when I refer to the Sub elsewhere as `Call Mathcode (Sec_Delay)` I get a *ByRef argument type mismatch* compile error:

[image: ByRef argument type mismatch]

The sheet `Sec_Delay` is initialized before it is called later in an OLEObject:

```
ElseIf Range("B1") = 3 And Range("S1") = 0 And Range("R1") = 1 Then
Set Sec_Delay = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, Pri_Delay)
Sec_Delay.Name = "Secondary Drive Timing Delay2"
    With Sec_Delay.Range("A2:S35")
        Pri_Delay.Range("A2:S35").Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

Dim obj2 As Object
Dim Code2 As String

    With Sec_Delay

        Set obj = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
                                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=279, _
                                Top:=210.75, Width:=109.5, Height:=24)
        obj.Name = "ButtonTest"
        obj.Object.Caption = "USER INPUT"

        Code = "Sub ButtonTest_Click()" & vbCrLf & _
            "UF_input.Show" & vbCrLf & _
            "End Sub"


        Set obj2 = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
                                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=277.5, _
                                Top:=236.25, Width:=111, Height:=24)
        obj2.Name = "ExecuteTest"
        obj2.Object.Caption = "Execute"

        Code2 = "Sub ExecuteTest_Click()" & vbCrLf & _
            "Call MathCode (Sec_Delay)" & vbCrLf & _
            "End Sub"


        With .Parent.VBProject.VBComponents(.CodeName).CodeModule
            .insertlines .countoflines + 1, Code
            .insertlines .countoflines + 1, Code2
        End With
    End With
```

Any idea why I am getting the ByRef error?

EDIT:

I adjusted the code a little bit to be:

```
Code2 = "Sub ExecuteTest_Click()" & vbCrLf & _
            "Dim Sec_Delay as Worksheet" & vbCrLf & _
            "Set Sec_Delay = ActiveSheet" & vbCrLf & _
            "MathCode Sec_Delay" & vbCrLf & _
            "End Sub"
```

I no longer get the ByRef error, but the the `MathCode` returns a bunch of zeros and even copies some data from the sheet `Pri_Delay` instead of using the data from `Sec_Delay.` If anyone might know why, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Where's the signature for `MathCode`? Also `Call` is obsolete/redundant, remove it.

Comment: @JeanRostan passing an object by value, means the method will be receiving a copy of the pointer rather than the pointer itself - "byval only cares about values" is a tad short & misleading.

Comment: Your revised code is assuming `ActiveSheet` will be the sheet you need to work with - could it be possible that `Pri_Delay` is the active sheet when that dynamic code runs? Of course it's hard to tell because you can't break in such code... looks like you need a more reliable way of passing the correct sheet reference around (or to ensure the correct sheet is active at that time). As for the original error, what's the declared type of `Sec_Delay`? If that's not `Worksheet`, then there's the type mismatch.

Comment: Could you try just `MathCode Me` to ensure MathCode is referencing the worksheet from where it is being called?